# An efficient approach to use unordered_map for representing a symmetric sparse matrix

Tags: c++, algorithm, matrix, typedef, unordered-map

I'm using `unordered_map` containers to represent symmetric sparse matrix. This is because I do not need to calculate all positions and I can use coordinates as *key* for fast data retrieval. My map looks like:

```
typedef std::size_t coord1D;
typedef std::pair<coord1D,coord1D> coord2D;
struct pair_hash {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2> &pair) const {
        return std::hash<T1>()(pair.first) ^ std::hash<T2>()(pair.second);
    }
};
typedef std::unordered_map<coord2D, std::shared_ptr<double>, pair_hash> my_map;
```

The thing is that every time I define a set key-value I need to provide the same value for two keys (*eg*. the pair i-j and j-i) because of the triangular nature of the matrix this represents, so:

```
my_map example;
example [std::make_pair(0,1)] = std::make_shared<double> (0.5);
example [std::make_pair(1,0)] = std::make_shared<double> (0.5);
```

I was thinking on a convenience function (as `operator=` cannot be overridden here) in order to avoid code redundancy, but I'm also wondering if there is a more efficient way to deal with this task. I think that the container used is the best possible (as `unordered_multimap` is not required).

Comment: Why don't you assure that the `i` is always `>= j` in a pair `i, j`? If you do this consistently in writing as well as reading you even could remove the redundancy of the duplicated entries. Is this a triangular matrix where the "other" triangle is just symmetrically or is the "other" triangle just 0? In the former case, you could "auto-fix" pairs `i, j` by a simple swap if the suggested condition is not met.

Comment: I cannot do that. When I latter search in the map, the order of `i` and `j` matters and I cannot guarantee which is larger. Let me explain this: Think that this "triangular matrix" corresponds to a relationship matrix of fathers and mothers: when I read data form one individual the information of the mother is in one column (say i) and the father in another (j). I cannot force i>j because other individual could have different mother and same father, with, i<j in that case. So the problem here is how I have to read the data, not that map[i,j] == map[j,i]

Comment: Uhm... Are we speaking about the same kind or triangular matrix? I had this in mind: [Wikipedia: Triangular matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix).

Comment: No, sorry for the error. I'm going to edit the question in order to avoid confusion.

Comment: What you describe is a matrix with strict symmetry respective to main diagonal. [Wikipedia: Symmetric matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix) In exactly such case, we used a triangular matrix to eliminate the redundancy (and the memory foot print). Though, calculating the actual cell in the internal 1d vector was a bit tricky. However, due to symmetry there is no difference between cell (i, j) and cell (j, i). Hence, we simply swap i and j whenever i < j. From outside it looks like a regular matrix but inside it's just the half of it (round about).

Comment: Please, note: You state that _the order of i and j matters_ but there is no (may not be a) difference between element i, j and element j, i in a symmetric matrix.

Comment: May be, another term, worth to be named. In our case, we handled a big but possibly dense matrix where you seem to have a [sparse matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_matrix). (This appears to me the only reason to store it in an `std::unordered_map` instead of a `std::vector`.)

Comment: Yes, it is this kind of matrix: most of relationships do not need to be calculated. About the order of i and j, think of an individual X who is son of damme 1 and sir 2, and another individual Y who is son of damme 3 and sir 2. This is because even if the relationship [1,2] equals relationship [2,1], when I read how to calculate parameters for X and Y I cannot change the order (we need to know who is the mode, 1 or 2). First, I read from X and get its value as map [1,2], but then I go to Y and have to get its value as map [3,2].

Comment: I guess I could use a convenience function to force the insertion of elements i>j AND the read of elements i>j. If it improved efficiency will be welcome :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building your matrix type on a typedef of an `unordered_map` does not seem to offer a good encapsulation.  Of course, at first sight, this seems to offer a very lean solution.  But in the end, the issue with `operator=` is the perfect demonstration of how this kind of construct conflicts with the [open/close principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle).

Therefore my proposal would be to wrap the underlying data structure in a class to improve encapsulation (for simplicity, I use double instead of a shared pointer):

```
using coord1D = std::size_t;    // time to forget about typedef ? 
using coord2D = std::pair<coord1D,coord1D>;
struct pair_hash {
    template <class T1, class T2>
    std::size_t operator() (const std::pair<T1, T2> &pair) const {
        return std::hash<T1>()(pair.first) ^ std::hash<T2>()(pair.second);
    }
};
class matrix {
    std::unordered_map<coord2D, double, pair_hash> m; 
public: 
    auto& operator[] (pair<int,int> p) { 
        if (p.first>p.second)
            p = make_pair(p.second, p.first);
        return m[p];
    }
};
```

In this case, you can transform the parameter to `operator[]` in order to make the matrix triangular by design, avoiding redundant code and redundant storage.

Demo:

```
matrix m;
m[make_pair(1,5)] = 27.2;
cout << m[make_pair(1,5)]<<" "<<m[make_pair(5,1)]<<endl;
```

[Online demo](https://ideone.com/aFGmN6)

Of course,  a better way would be to define a general matrix, and derive it into a a specialized triangular matrix where the coordinate transformation takes place.

Comment: Very elaborated answer, and this seems a very reasonable solution. Thank you very much! :)